# AWS S3: How to change an HTTP Header of a single object in a S3 bucket via CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

As the question implies I want to change/set some HTTP headers for a single object in a S3 bucket via CLI. This is what I have tried so far:

```
aws s3 sync --delete --acl public-read --cache-control \
max-age=31536000 --expires "Mon, 01 Oct 2035 20:30:00 GMT" \
js/jquery-blockui/jquery.blockUI.min.js \
s3://mybucket/js/jquery-blockui/jquery.blockUI.min.js --dryrun
```

The problem is, that `aws s3 sync` tells me that he could not find the file `/home/user/somedir/js/jquery-blockui/jquery.blockUI.min.js/` (see the last slash - the file DOES exist actually) on my file system:

```
warning: Skipping file
/home/user/somedir/js/jquery-blockui/jquery.blockUI.min.js/.
File does not exist.
```

So `aws s3 sync` does only expect a directory to be passed as the source? Does anyone has an idea, how to do that for a single file? I want to write a script and pass some files, which need to be altered - that's why I am asking. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### `aws s3 cp` is your friend :)

This should work:

```
aws s3 cp --acl public-read --cache-control \
max-age=31536000 --expires "Mon, 01 Oct 2035 20:30:00 GMT" \
js/jquery-blockui/jquery.blockUI.min.js \
s3://mybucket/js/jquery-blockui/jquery.blockUI.min.js
```

Note that `--delete` is not supported with `aws s3 cp` but that's a minor. You can always delete it locally after upload with good old `/bin/rm` :)

And yes, `aws s3 sync` only works recursively between local directories and S3 folders, not on single files.

Hope that helps :)